# Why is Ubuntu NOT checking whether an app is already installed?

Tags: software-installation, updates, 18.04

It would be so nice if Ubuntu would not just install an app which is already installed! In 99% of the cases it makes absolutely no sense to install an app multiple times. **Can I configure it somehow to check before blindly install an app?** E.g.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Is there also a way to configure it that it updates an app if the version of the installed version is smaller than the new one?**

Comment: It's not possible to install the same package from repositories multiple times. What you're looking at here are different packages, one being the main application and one providing some kind of additional features, plugins or data, which may be a required or optional dependency.

Comment: If that really is the identical application twice, then only the names in the Ubuntu Software application  is doubled. It will however install twice if you chose to install a newer version from a snap.

Comment: Oh right, snaps and traditional apt/deb packages are independent, so you can install both a snap and a deb package of the same application. Not sure how exactly they are presented in the software center currently, that might be an issue.

Comment: Totally agree the interface needs to be way less confusing.